# pexpect determine if ssh exists: using ps and grep

Tags: python, ssh, tunnel, pexpect

I am trying to do a script to automate ssh tunnelling on Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit. It is based on the ssh_tunnel example found in the Pexpect module (http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#ssh_tunnel.py)

But there is a problem with running the code on my machine. I wanted to check if there are any active, non-defunct ssh tunnels already running. If I check this in the terminal, I get ssh-agent and ssh  coming up:

```
    user@comp$ ps -e|grep ssh
     3578 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
     9686 pts/0    00:10:31 ssh <defunct>
    10955 pts/0    00:00:02 ssh
```

So I tried filtering the results using the -v option (invert selection) of grep, I am able to get active tunnels. This will allow me to determine if I need to open a new tunnel:

```
    user@comp$ ps -e|grep ssh|grep -v agent|grep -v def
    10995 pts/0    00:00:00 ssh
```

Unfortunately, if I call the above command using pexpect.spawn, and then do the expect as follows:

```
ps = pexpect.spawn ('ps -e|grep ssh | grep -v agent | grep -v def')
res1 = ps.expect (['ssh', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
```

res1 returns as 1, indicating pexpect.EOF (there is no ssh process found)

What am I doing wrong here? Else, is there another way to check if there is already an ssh running so that I will not open another

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/) for issuing commands over ssh.

```
$ pip install fabric
```

Here, I'll run the command on my local machine (127.0.0.1) as an example.

```
from fabric.api import run, env

command = 'ps -e|grep ssh | grep -v agent | grep -v def'
env.host_string = '127.0.0.1'
env.password = 'mypassword'
run(command)
...
[127.0.0.1] out:  4921 ??         0:00.06 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  4924 ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  5196 ??         0:00.00 /usr/libexec/launchproxy /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  5197 ??         0:00.04 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  5198 ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  5199 ??         0:00.03 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  5200 ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  5201 ??         0:00.06 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  5204 ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
[127.0.0.1] out:  4920 ttys002    0:00.02 ssh smlstvnh@127.0.0.1
[127.0.0.1] out:  5242 ttys004    0:00.00 grep ssh
```

[Documentation on fabric.api.run](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run)

[Documentation on fabric.api.env](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#), [host_string](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#host-string), and [password](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/usage/env.html#password)

Comment: I would also like tp automate the task of keeping it open (i.e. I would like to have the password entered automatically when I reconnect. Can you tell me if this can be done using fabric?

Comment: Definitely. You could also use ssh keys. The answer is updated to define `env.password`